# How can I rewrite values from an array into a second array with each 2 letters being flipped? (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

This is for a homework assignment which I have been working on for quite a while now but have not been able to figure out. Here are the exact instructions from my teacher if you need them; it is at number five that I am stuck:

> (1) Have the user enter a sentence that they want to have encoded.
>   (2) If the number of characters in the message is odd, concatenate a space  (" ") to their message so that our message will always be an even number of letters. 
>   (3) Now create a new char[], call it unCoded where each element is a letter from your secret message.
>   (4) Now create an empty second char[], call it coded,  and define its length equal to the length of the other char[], unCoded.
>   (5) Now write the values from the uncoded array into the coded array, but flipping each 2 letters.
>   (6) Then write out the original uncoded message.
>   (7) Then write out the new coded message.

He also said step 5 must be done in a loop.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

What I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the sentence you want encoded: ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        int remainder = userInput.Length % 2;

        if (remainder!=0)
        {
            userInput = userInput + " ";
        }
        char[] unCoded = userInput.ToArray();
        char[] coded=unCoded;
        //coded.Length = unCoded.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < unCoded.Length; i=i+2)
        {
            coded[0] = unCoded[1];
            coded[1] = unCoded[0];
        }
        string encoded = new string(coded);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", userInput);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", encoded);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Sooo... what do you have so far? What's it doing that you don't expect?

Comment: So you flip one in the pair, `coded[0]` gets assigned to `unCoded[1]`. I'm sure you can recognize that the next thing to do is assigned `coded[1]` to `unCoded[0]`. Think about how you could address the fact that you've got the array indexes hardcoded right now.

Comment: Yes, but how can I make the code do this for every single letter regardless of the length of users input?

Comment: You've got that `i` hanging around... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your loop you don't use the loop parameter, so you just change up the first two values several times. Consider what you are doing in your loop to be the first step of what you actually want to achieve. Do it using the "i" variable and knowing that it's first value is 0. Then when i "grows", the loop will do the same for the next two values.

> so just put i in place of 0 and i+1 in place of 1